# How to handle timeout in Async Socket?

Tags: .net, sockets, asynchronous, asyncsocket

I have a code that using async socket to send message to client and expecting response from it. If the client did not reply in a specified internal it will considers timeout. Some of the article in Internet suggest to use WaitOne, but this will blocks the thread and defers the purpose of using I/O completion.

What is the best way to handle timeout in async socket?

```
 Sub OnSend(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
       Dim socket As Socket = CType(ar.AsyncState ,Socket)
       socket.EndSend(ar)

       socket.BeginReceive(Me.ReceiveBuffer, 0, Me.ReceiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnReceive), socket)

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can’t timeout or cancel asynchronous `Socket` operations.

All you can do is start your own `Timer` which closes the `Socket`—the callback will then be immediately called and the `EndX` function will come back with an `ObjectDisposedException` if you call it.  Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class AsyncClass
{
     Socket sock;
     Timer timer;
     byte[] buffer;
     int timeoutflag;

     public AsyncClass()
     {
          sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream,
                ProtocolType.Tcp);

          buffer = new byte[256];
     }

     public void StartReceive()
     {
          IAsyncResult res = sock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length,
                SocketFlags.None, OnReceive, null);

          if(!res.IsCompleted)
          {
                timer = new Timer(OnTimer, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
          }
     }

     void OnReceive(IAsyncResult res)
     {
          if(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref timeoutflag, 1, 0) != 0)
          {
                // the flag was set elsewhere, so return immediately.
                return;
          }

          // we set the flag to 1, indicating it was completed.

          if(timer != null)
          {
                // stop the timer from firing.
                timer.Dispose();
          }

          // process the read.

          int len = sock.EndReceive(res);
     }

     void OnTimer(object obj)
     {
          if(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref timeoutflag, 2, 0) != 0)
          {
                // the flag was set elsewhere, so return immediately.
                return;
          }

          // we set the flag to 2, indicating a timeout was hit.

          timer.Dispose();
          sock.Close(); // closing the Socket cancels the async operation.
     }
}
```

Comment: I found a similar answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231816/net-async-socket-timeout-check-thread-safety .
The idea is to have a single timer to look after all the existing connection to check is it timeout.