# .NET: How can I keep using a socket after a read timeout?

Tags: sockets, timeout

In my application, I want to have a polling loop which blocks on a socket receive operation but times out after 100 ms. This would allow me to exit the loop when I want (e.g. the user clicks something in the UI) while avoiding using a busy loop or Thread.sleep.

However, it seems that once a .NET socket is opened, it can only time out once. After the first timeout, any calls that would block throw an exception immediately.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973342/how-to-handle-timeout-in-async-socket), "you can’t timeout or cancel asynchronous `Socket` operations." Why not? Is there a better way to approach the problem in the .NET world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a non-busy polling loop on a .NET socket, you can use the Poll socket method, as follows:

```
for (keepGoing) {
    if (mySocket.Poll(1000 * timeout_milliseconds, SelectMode.SelectRead)) {
        // Assert: mySocket.Available > 0.
        // TODO: Call mySocket.Receive or a related method
    }
}
```

In this case, `Poll` returns false if no data becomes available to read from the socket within the specified timeout. Another thread can reset `keepGoing` to false if it wants to cleanly shut down the polling loop.