# Can Socket still be used after Timeout?

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-4.0, timeout, socketexception

Is it possible to continue using a .NET `Socket` after synchronous Send/Receive method throws a `SocketException` because of exceeding the specified Send/Receive Timeout? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591235/net-how-can-i-keep-using-a-socket-after-a-read-timeout?rq=1) it is said that methods will throw exception immediately after the first Timeout. I would like to get some information about what socket will do(close itself?) and if socket can be used normally after handling the `SocketException`(Timeout). I haven't seen anything related on MSDN docs.

Comment: The Socket won't do anything to itself if it's just timed out - you can retry the Send/Receive again.

Comment: If the Socket threw an exception it means there is no connection.  You certainly can still use the same Socket reference provided you make a attempt to make new connection of course.

Comment: @Ramhound That is not correct. A timeout does not destroy the connection.

Comment: @EJP - I didn't say it did.

Comment: @Ramhound You most certainly did say exactly that: 'if the Socket threw an exception it means there is no connection'. That is incorrect in the case of a timeout exception.

Comment: @EJP - In the case of a timeout exception it would indicate there was never a connection established thus the no connection to be destroyed.

Comment: @Ramhound When you've made up your mind what you are and aren't saying, in the case of a *read* timeout it indicates there *was* a connection to read, and after the timeout the connection is still viable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the comments given saying that socket can be used normally after timeout, though I haven't tried myself.