# Cancel a static async function with a timeout

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, c#-5.0, winrt-async

I need to cancel the UpdateDatabase() function if it takes more than 2 minutes. I 've tried *cancellationtokens* and *timers* but I couldn't manage to solve this (couldn't find any appropriate example).

Could you please help me on this?

**App.xaml.cs**

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
   await PerformDataFetch();
}

internal async Task PerformDataFetch()
{
   await LocalStorage.UpdateDatabase();
}
```

**LocalStorage.cs**

```
public async static Task<bool> UpdateDatabase()
{
  await ..// DOWNLOAD FILES
  await ..// CHECK FILES
  await ..// RUN CONTROLES
}
```

***Edited my classes according to answers.***

*App.xaml.cs* stays as same. *UpdateDatabase()* is edited and the new method *RunUpdate()* added in *LocalStorage.cs*:

```
public static async Task UpdateDatabase()
{
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    source.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)); // how much time has the update process
    Task<int> task = Task.Run(() => RunUpdate(source.Token), source.Token);

    await task;
}

private static async Task<int> RunUpdate(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    await ..// DOWNLOAD FILES
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    await ..// CHECK FILES
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    await ..// RUN CONTROLES
}
```

I know this is not the only way and could be better but a good point to start for newbies like me.

Comment: you can use WaitOne if you can wait till the call finishes with a timeout or you need to implement your own timer.. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973342/how-to-handle-timeout-in-async-socket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a `CancellationToken` to the `UpdateDatabase` function and check the token after each await by calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134310/how-to-cancel-a-task-in-await)

Comment: Also, pass the token to each method you call that takes a token.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
const int millisecondsTimeout = 2500;
Task updateDatabase = LocalStorage.UpdateDatabase();
if (await Task.WhenAny(updateDatabase, Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout)) == updateDatabase)
{
    //code
}
else
{
    //code
}
```